# Initparams from ASP.NET in silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight-3.0

How do you **dynamically** populate the silverlight InitParameters collection fron ASP.NET (C#, not script) in Silverlight 3.0?  Now that they recommend an object tag instead of an asp:Silverlight tag it does not seem to have any sort of 'run at server object' to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around this with a hidden input tag in HTML.  ASP.NET can set the value, Silverlight can access it via the HtmlDocument.